# Is there a bug in formula 7 in Goodman (1960) "On the Exact Variance of Products"?

Tags: variance

Formula 6 in Goodman (1960) is presented as:

[image: formula 6]

Formula 7 in Goodman (1960) is presented as:

[image: formula 7]

Instead of the second "s^2(**y**)" in formula 7 I would expect "s^2(**x**)". Can anyone confirm or disprove this assumption?

Full text of Goodman (1960) can be found here: [http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cga/var/2281592.pdf](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ecga/var/2281592.pdf)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Referring to equation $(9)$ in your reference will answer the question.

Comment: Ok, so (6) and (9) are correct and (7) is incorrect, I assume. Thanks!